# 3D plot of x1 and x2 versus z, where z is defined as z = x1^2 + 0.1*x1 in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Heres my code:

```
x1 = seq(from=0,to=1,length.out=10)
x2 = seq(from=0,to=1,length.out=10)
x1x2 = expand.grid(x1,x2)

z = (x1)^2+0.1*(x1)

z = length(length(x1x2))
x1x2z = data.frame(x1x2,z)
x1x2z


colnames(xyz) = c("x1=","x2","z")
head(x1x2z,3)
plot_ly(x1x2z,x1=~x,x2=~x2,z=~z,color="red")
```

I am getting the error:

```
No trace type specified:
  Based on info supplied, a 'scatter3d' trace seems appropriate.
  Read more about this trace type -> https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter3d
Error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled:
* Length 10: Column `x`
* Length 100: Columns `y`, `z`
```

Comment: So what happens when you follow the advice in that apparently exceedingly informative error message? Also, the length of a data.frame is NOT the number of items or for that matter the number of rows. and `length(length(x))` would probably always be 1.

Comment: And where the error about "Tibble columns" is coming from is not at all clear. You have obviously not included all of your code.

Comment: @42- "exceedingly informative...". :D :D Love it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to tidy up in the code from above.
Some naming was not correct in the example, which made the debbuging a bit trickier than necessary.

The main issue with the code was not to set the type of plot you wanted.
this can be done with the type argument of plot_ly. You can use this function in the following way with the use of add trace

```
plot_ly(x1x2z, type="scatter3d", mode="markers") %>% add_trace(
x = x1x2z$x1,
y = x1x2z$x2,
z = x1x2z$z,
marker = list(  color = 'rgb(17, 157, 255)',
  size = 20,
  line = list(
    color = 'rgb(231, 99, 250)',
    width = 2
  )
  ))
```

[output image for the data in the question and the ploting function above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BMtk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I debugged your code and used scatterplot3d instead of plot_ly.

```
> x1 = seq(from=0,to=1,length.out=50) # 10 seems too few
> x2 = seq(from=0,to=1,length.out=50)
> x1x2 = expand.grid(x1,x2)

> z = (x1)^2+0.1*(x1)

> #z = length(length(x1x2))  # Why do this?
> x1x2z = data.frame(x1x2,z)
> colnames(x1x2z) = c("x1","x2","z")
> head(x1x2z,3)
          x1 x2           z
1 0.00000000  0 0.000000000
2 0.02040816  0 0.002457309
3 0.04081633  0 0.005747605

> library(scatterplot3d)
> scatterplot3d(x1x2z, color="red")
```

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with the `rgl` package:

```
library(rgl)
plot3d(function(x1,x2) (x1)^2+0.1*(x1), xlim=0:1, ylim=0:1, col = "red", zlab = "z")
```

This produces this plot:

[image: screenshot]